# Price comparison database - put price data in main table, in one separate table or in many product tables?

Tags: sql, database

I'm trying to build a price comparison database with n products and a definitive but changing number of vendors that sell these products.

For my price comparison database, I need to store both current prices for a product across different vendors and historical prices (one lowest price).

As I see it, I have 2 options to design the database tables:

**1.** Put all vendor prices into the main table.

I know how many vendors there will be and if I add or remove a vendor I can add or remove a column.

Historical prices (lowest price on certain date across all vendors), goes into a separate table with a product name, a price and a date.

**2.** Have one table for products and one table for prices

I will have only the static attribute data in the main table such as categories, attributes etc and then add prices to a separate product table where I store price, vendor, date in it and I can store the lowest price as a pseudo-vendor in that table for each date or I can store it in a separate table as well.

Which method would you suggest and am I missing something?

Comment: None of them, at least not completely. Relational tables aren't spread sheets so forget about adding data by adding columns. You add rows to add data. So #1 certainly not. #2 is basically OK but don't materialize the lowest price. Given a product (ID) and period in time you can always query the lowest price for that product in that period of time. Vendors should also have their own table for their "static" attributes.

Comment: But the problem with such "Help me make my data model" questions is that they're typically to broad for SO, unless it is a specific question about a specific design decision. They would require detailed knowledge about what should be modeled in the real world where even a small scope typically raises a lot of questions during the design process. And SO is designed as a Q & A platform and not for such interactive processes

Answer (score 1):

You should store the base data in a normalized format that contains all the history.  This means that you have tables for:

- `products`, with one row per product and the static information about the products.
- `vendors`, with one row per vendor and the static information about the vendor.
- `prices`, with one row per price along with the date and product and vendor.

You can get the current and lowest prices using a query, such as:

```
select pr.*
from (select pr.*, min(price) over (partition by product) as min_price
             row_number() over (partition by product, vendor order by price_datetime desc) as seqnum
      from prices pr
      where pr.product_id = XXX
     ) pr
where seqnum = 1;
```

For performance, you want an index on `prices(product, vendor, price_datetime desc)`.

Eventually, you may find that this query runs too slowly.  In that case, you will then consider optimizations.  One optimization would simply be storing the latest date for each price/vendor combination using a trigger, along with the minimum price in the `products` table -- presumably using triggers.

Another would be maintaining a summary table for each product and vendor using triggers.  However, that is probably not how you should start the endeavor.

However, you might be surprised at how well the above query can perform on your data.